# Handling image uploads with multer and mongodb in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, multer

I am writing a simple blog style application for a business I am building a website for. So far I've implemented a login system, a basic blog system, and am now working on making it so that a user can upload images to go along with their blog post. Here I run into trouble, I'm only going to handle the new blog post function right now, and I'll figure out the edit myself.

So a user, signed in and is an admin, clicks on New Post and is brought to new.ejs which is just a form like so:

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4">New Article</h1>

        <form action="/articles" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
            <%- include('_form_fields') %>
            
        </form>
    </div>
```

The _form_fields.ejs includes my actual forms, that has the file uploading and submission button:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title</label>
      <input required value="<%= article.title %>" type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control">
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Description</label>
      <textarea name="description" id="description" class="form-control"><%= article.description %></textarea>
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="markdown">Markdown</label>
      <textarea required name="markdown" id="markdown" class="form-control"><%= article.markdown %></textarea>
    </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="image">Image</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <a href="/" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" value = "upload" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

The routing for new.ejs is handled by articles.js, which is in a folder called routes. articles.js handles all the routes for articles, creating a new one, editing one, and deleting one. This is the code just for creating a new one:

```
const express = require('express');
const Article = require('./../models/article');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const { extname, join: pathJoin } = require('path');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads/'); // Specify the destination folder
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
    const extension = path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, uniqueSuffix + extension); // Generate a unique filename
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const saveArticleAndRedirect = (path) => {
  return async (req, res, next) => {
    let article = req.article;
    article.title = req.body.title;
    article.description = req.body.description;
    article.markdown = req.body.markdown;

    try {
      if (req.file) {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1e9);
        const extension = extname(req.file.originalname);
        const filename = uniqueSuffix + extension;
        const imagePath = pathJoin('public/uploads/', filename);
        req.file.mv(imagePath, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            throw new Error('Failed to upload the image file');
          }
        });
        article.image = imagePath;
      }

      article = await article.save();
      res.redirect(`/articles/${article.slug}`);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      res.render(`articles/${path}`, { article: article, error: e.message });
    }
  };
};


  function isAdmin(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.role === 'ADMIN') {
      next();
    } else {
      res.redirect('/'); // Redirect non-admin users to the homepage
    }
  }
  
  // Admin-only route for creating new articles
  router.get('/new', isAdmin, (req, res) => {
    res.render('articles/new', { article: new Article() })
  })

  router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.file) {
      console.log('No file received!');
    } else {
      console.log(req.file);
    }
    req.article = new Article(); // Create a new article instance
    next();
  }, saveArticleAndRedirect('new'));
```

And finally my article.js schema saved in a file called models:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const marked = require('marked')
const slugify = require('slugify')
const createDomPurify = require('dompurify')
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')
const dompurify = createDomPurify(new JSDOM().window)

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  markdown: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  sanitizedHtml: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String
  }
})

articleSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  if (this.title) {
    this.slug = slugify(this.title, { lower: true, strict: true })
  }

  if (this.markdown) {
    this.sanitizedHtml = dompurify.sanitize(marked.parse(this.markdown))
  }

  next()
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)
```

Currently if I go to upload an image in the new article route, hitting the save button once will upload the image (I presume) and the second time will post the article. If I go into public/uploads then the picture is saved there, however the image field isn't populated in the mongodb. And the console output is as follows:

```
{
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'bigfootfeed.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'public/uploads/',
  filename: '1686845869591-191454535.jpg',
  path: 'public\\uploads\\1686845869591-191454535.jpg',
  size: 128712
}
TypeError: req.file.mv is not a function
    at
No file received!
```

So I believe that somewhere along the way the file isn't being properly saved to the database. However, I have tried troubleshooting as much as I can and I haven't found the error. I assume its something staring me in the face but I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

What's missing in your route is registering multer as middleware for handling the file right before *your* middleware. Try this:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('image'), async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.file) {
      console.log('No file received!');
    } else {
      console.log(req.file);
    }
    req.article = new Article(); // Create a new article instance
    next();
  }, saveArticleAndRedirect('new'));
```

From multer [docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html):

> .single(fieldname)
> Accept a single file with the name fieldname. The single file will be stored in req.file.